# Expression tree for groupby with where clause and than select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

From UI dynamic column are coming as parameter in API and based on the parameter I have to fetch data from database. 
Example : In the below code, based on the column if condition linq query is being executed. Now I want to make it generic so that it serve if new column condition come in future.

```
public List<string> GetFilteredTypeAhead(string searchText,string searchForRole,int fiscalyear,int fiscalPeriod)
        {
 if (searchForRole == "column1")
            {
                var accounts = (from a in _context.Account
                                where a.column1.StartsWith(searchText) && a.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod && a.FiscalYear ==fiscalyear
                                group a.column1 by a.column2 into g
                                select g.Key).ToList();
                return accounts;
            }
            else if(searchForRole == "column2")
            {
                var accounts = (from a in _context.Account
                                where a.column2.StartsWith(searchText) && a.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod && a.FiscalYear == fiscalyear
                                group a.column2 by a.column2 into g
                                select g.Key).ToList();
                return accounts;
            }
            else if (searchForRole == "column3")
            {
                var accounts = (from a in _context.Account
                                where a.column3.StartsWith(searchText) && a.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod && a.FiscalYear == fiscalyear
                                group a.column3 by a.column3 into g
                                select g.Key).ToList();
                return accounts;
            }
            else if (searchForRole == "column4")
            {
                var accounts = (from a in _context.Account
                                where a.column4.StartsWith(searchText) && a.FiscalPeriod.Equals(fiscalPeriod) && a.FiscalYear.Equals(fiscalyear)
                                group a.column4 by a.column4 into g
                                select g.Key).ToList();
                return accounts;
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<string>();
            }
        }
```

To convert it to generic. I created a expression tree.

```
static IQueryable<T> ConvertToExpression<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyValue, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, int fiscalyear, int fiscalPeriod)
        {
            ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
            MemberExpression m = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, propertyInfo);
            ConstantExpression c = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            Expression call = Expression.Call(m, mi, c);

            PropertyInfo propertyInfoFiscalPeriod = typeof(T).GetProperty("FiscalPeriod");
            MemberExpression memberPropertyFiscalPeriod = Expression.Property(e, propertyInfoFiscalPeriod);
            ConstantExpression right = Expression.Constant(fiscalPeriod);
            Expression equalsFiscalPeriod = Expression.Equal(memberPropertyFiscalPeriod, Expression.Convert(right, typeof(Int16)));

            PropertyInfo propertyInfoFiscalYear = typeof(T).GetProperty("FiscalYear");
            MemberExpression memberPropertyFiscalYear = Expression.Property(e, propertyInfoFiscalYear);
            right = Expression.Constant(fiscalyear);
            Expression equalsFiscalYear = Expression.Equal(memberPropertyFiscalYear, Expression.Convert(right, typeof(Int16)));

            Expression combineExpression = Expression.And(equalsFiscalPeriod, equalsFiscalYear);

            Expression predicateBody = Expression.And(call, combineExpression);

            Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicateBody, e);
            return query.Where(lambda);
        }
```

And To call it I used code like below
"searchForRole" comes as parameter in as "column1","column2" etc

```
 PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Account).GetProperty(searchForRole);

            IQueryable<Account> query = _context.Account;

            query = ConvertToExpression(query, searchText, propertyInfo,fiscalyear,fiscalPeriod);



            var list = query.ToList();
```

Now this is working fine but the result having duplicate records. I wanted to have some distinct or group by on passed parameter column. In Simple words I wanted to remove if condition and make my search method generic. Please help.

Comment: The best way to query dynamically is by using System.Linq.Dynamic library
you can find it from Nuget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but IMHO it's better to keep the dynamic parts at minimum and use the C# compile time safety as much as possible.

The sample query in question

```
var accounts = (from a in _context.Account
                where a.column1.StartsWith(searchText) && a.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod && a.FiscalYear ==fiscalyear
                group a.column1 by a.column1 into g
                select g.Key).ToList();
```

can be rewritten as follows

```
var accounts = _context.Account
    .Where(a => a.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod && a.FiscalYear == fiscalyear)
    .Select(a => a.column1)
    .Where(c => c.StartsWith(searchText))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

As you can see, the only dynamic part is `a => a.column1` of type `Expression<Func<Account, string>>`. So all you need is a method like this:

```
static Expression<Func<T, M>> MemberSelector<T>(string name)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(name);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, M>>(body, parameter);
}
```

and to replace

```
.Select(a => a.column1)
```

with

```
.Select(MemberSelector<Account, string>(searchForRole))
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks working. Just wanted to check about func return type "M" in expression - Expression<Func<T, M>>  , Can we convert it to custom return DTO like ``` public class FilterDto
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }```  and then convert to toList()

Comment: Such requirements is good to be provided in advance, because they might require totally different solution. It's not clear what goes to `Value` and what goes to `Text` property of the DTO etc. Also the comment space is limited. Consider posting another question including exactly what you need. Cheers.